# Django - Categories dropdown

Tags: python, django, django-models, view, django-1.6

I'm trying to create a form to add a new 'Service' (or edit an existing one) and show a dropdown list of categories, so the user can select which category the service belongs to. 
I know this must be a newbie question, but I've been investigating for days and it's becoming frustrating :(

For some reason I see the form and the list of categories, but when I save it I get this error:

**Cannot assign "": "Service.category" must be a "Category" instance.**

This is what I have at the moment:

This is my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField('Nombre de Categoria', max_length=250)

        class Meta:
                verbose_name_plural = "categories"

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class Service(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
        name = models.CharField('Nombre del Servicio', max_length=250)
        duration = models.IntegerField('Duracion', default=0)
        price = models.FloatField('Precio', default=0.0)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name
```

and my `forms.py`:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Select, ModelChoiceField
from services.models import Service, Category
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Field, Fieldset, Button, Submit, Div, Row, HTML
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import AppendedText

class ServiceForm(ModelForm):
        helper = FormHelper()
        helper.form_tag = False
        helper.disable_csrf = True
        helper.layout = Layout (
                Div(
                        Div('name', css_class='col-sm-3'),
                        Div(AppendedText('duration', 'minutos'), css_class='col-sm-3'),
                        Div(AppendedText('price', '&euro;'), css_class='col-sm-2'),
                        css_class='row'
                ),
        )
        class Meta:
                model = Service

class CategoryForm(ModelForm):
        name = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())

        helper = FormHelper()
        helper.form_tag = False
        helper.disable_csrf = True
        helper.layout = Layout (
                Div(
                        Div('name', css_class='col-sm-6'),
                        css_class='row'
                ),
        )
        class Meta:
                model = Category
                widgets = { 'name': Select() }
```

this is the `views.py` file:

```
def manage_service(request, service_id=None):
        # Verifico si el request viene con un service_id
        if service_id:
                service = get_object_or_404(Service, pk=service_id)
                extra_value = 0
        else:
                service = Service()
                extra_value = 1

        CategoryInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Category, Service, form=CategoryForm, extra=extra_value)

        if request.method == "POST":
                form = ServiceForm(request.POST, instance=service)
                category_formset = CategoryInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=service)
                if form.is_valid():
                        service = form.save(commit=False)
                        if category_formset.is_valid():
                                service.save()
                                category_formset.save()
                                messages.add_message(request,
                                        messages.SUCCESS,
                                        mark_safe('Servicio <strong>%s</strong> guardado correctamente' % service.name))
                                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('services:index'))
        else:
                form = ServiceForm(instance=service)
                category_formset = CategoryInlineFormSet(instance=service)

        return render(request, 'services/service_form.html', {
                'form': form,
                'category_formset': category_formset,
        })
```

and `service_form.html`:

```
#...
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="" role="form" method='post' action=''>
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% crispy form %}
        {% crispy category_formset category_formset.form.helper %}

        <p>
                <button type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Servicio</button>
                <button type="submit" value="Borrar" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar Servicio</button>
        </p>
</form>
#...
```

Could you please guys let me know what I'm doing wrong? :(

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Witch line exactly is raising this error?

Comment: it seems to be this one (views.py, line 48): 'category_formset': category_formset,

Comment: This is happening because, category field is not nullable, and you are trying to save null against it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @karthikr. Could you please let me know how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either allow null values in the database, or handle the same in the form (ensure required=True)